# Modification of svn:log with pre-revprop-change hook

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, hook

Is there any way for the **pre-revprop-change** hook script to know what is the **current value of svn:log *before modification***?
I know that the hook script receives, as standard input, the intended new value.  But I need the script to verify what the current value is before it is modified.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
svnlook author|date|log -r<HEAD_REVISION> <PATH_TO_REPO>
```

To find head revision you can use

```
svnlook youngest <PATH_TO_REPO>
```